# How to find normals to an edge in an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

I am doing some work related to eye images. 
  I did edge detection to it. The edge is like a curve and not continuous. I have to assume it to be continuous and find normals to that curve. How do I find the normals to it using MATLAB?

you can see the image below.

[image: Edge image]

I want to find the normals to the upper curve.
I hope that I was clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

Even though it seems unintuitive, the edge direction at every pixel is a pretty good estimate of the normal. This would be the simplest solution, because it doesn't involve any curve fitting.

In MATLAB, you can find pixel-wise edge directions using the Sobel filter:

```
[BW,thresh,gv,gh] = edge(I,'sobel');
edgeDir = atan2(gv, gh);
```

This gives you the edge directions as angles in radians.

Comment: Thanks for answering. By doing the above process I am getting the edgeDir at every pixel. How can I do it for only upper curve(or lower curve)? How can I make equations of normals for the curve?

Comment: To fit a line to the normal at any edge point, compute the edge direction theta, compute the slope as m = tan(theta). Take the edge pixel coordinates (x, y) and solve equation y = mx + c to compute the constant c. You then have the equation for the normal. To distinguish between the upper and lower curves, you may need to do curve fitting and compare the y coordinates of the curve's focal point.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I got the idea. Can you help me out with curve fitting? I didn't find anything related to image. It was given just for a several points. If you have any link, please post it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider curve fitting (MSE based or some other criteria) to the data. I believe a second order will do good for the upper curve, and once you have a model you can can calculate the tangent and normal at each point.

Comment: can you please describe me in detail. How can I select only the upper curve? I dont think like selecting based on giving the range of rows because for a certain row both of the curves exist.

Comment: You may try a few methods. You may split the image into sub-images and threshold there. You can try and fit a 2nd order model which will find some-kind of "center" line between them and choose the numbers above this line.

Comment: can you tell me how can I fit circular arc to it. I want to do curve fitting to the lower curve(say). I have isolated it like you said. I want to do curve fitting(circular) to it

Answer (score 0):

As Zaphod recommended the normal is perpendicular to the edge.  You don't need to do curve fitting, you can use back projection to identify the focal point of the curve.

Start at each edge point along the curve and draw a line from curve in the direction of the normal.  Draw the line by incrementing the value of each pixel the line passes through.  Once you do this for all the edges you would hope to find two pixels with higher values then the rest, one for each of your curves.  You should then know by there locations which is the focal point for each curve.

Comment: How can I traverse along the curve(upper or lower)? Can you tell me how can I run through a curve to be able to draw lines from coding point of view?